# Delete rows based on match column B E and then Column F if = 12 or a row contains 12

Tags: excel, vba

[link to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/093UI.jpg)I am trying to find a solution to remove rows of data from a workbook based on multiple criteria
Column B is company name
Column E is year
Column F is months.
The complex part is that there some instances where Column B and E are matched more than once , as there are different month values which can be 3 , 6 , 9 , 12. I need to find a way to delete all rows which does not have a monthly value of 12. but I need to keep the rows with monthly values less than 12 , if one of the matched rows from B and E has a value of 12

At present I just have this code , but I could only get it to work to remove all months not equal to 12. there is also an addition check , on column  8 , if that = 0 then delete row

```
lr = w2.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
With w2.ActiveSheet
  Dim r As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long
  For r = lr To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(r, 8) = 0 Or Cells(r, 6) <> 12 Then
      Rows(r).Delete
    End If
  Next r
End With
```

I want to be able have a table of contents left that has any zero data in column 8 removed and only have monthly data that contains 12 or if multiple month values less than 12 , but one of matches equals 12 then keep all those months

Comment: For starters, `Rows.Count` should be fully qualified like: `w2.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` or it will refer to the active sheet instead of the one you want. The same goes for your `Rows(r)` and `Cells()` - they are not qualified just by including them in a `With`

Comment: thanks , this was just a small snippet of my code , id select the the correct sheet . my main issue is trying to not delete the month values if they are less than 12 if one of the matches has a 12 .

Comment: Maybe use COUNTIFS?

Comment: could you please let me know how I could use countifs to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    'Change sheet name if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of Column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            If .Range("F" & i).Value <> 12 And (.Range("B" & i).Value <> 12 And .Range("E" & i).Value <> 12) Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Range F is the only Column that has the month values. I need to find a way if Column B company name and Column E year is matched. Then if there are more than one instance of this match due to multiple month numbers being added, so say we have comp1 year 2019 , then we have 3 rows with this matched criteria . with column F , months 3 , 9 , 12. . As one of those matched months is 12 , I need to keep all the rows. If comp2 2019 had 3 rows of data , with months 3 , 6 , 9. Then these would need to be deleted as none of those months equal 12.

Comment: please upload an image with the initial data and the desirable outcome.

Comment: I have added a link to the table at the top of the post. In this example , All the data should be kept for company AA , as there is an instance of 12 in one of the rows. All company BB rows deleted